# internationalization in android

Tags: android, localization, internationalization, android-sqlite

A complete document is given by Android developer website for Internationalization in android. But till I have some question on this.

Some language starts there word from left to right, top to bottom.

Some language starts from right to left, bottom to top.

Some language moves vertically means from top to bottom one line again top to bottom second line and so on.

Question: 1. How to support these languages? Because in Android(Edit Text) it allow to write from left to write and from top to bottom.

2. Some of the String I am storing in Sqlite database. So this is possible to store all the language in Sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

You can use this `android:textDirection="anyRtl"`

Please check this post for [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301191/how-to-make-my-edit-text-type-right-to-left).

Comment: ...thanks for reply..How I will store different language characters in SQLITE database.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how, because I have no experience in SQLITE, but I think that you must change character encoding in some which support characters you need.