# Arabic in EditText is Right Aligned, but the first few characters do not show

Tags: android, android-edittext, alignment, arabic

I have EditText with Arabic Text.

When I type Arabic text, the text appears as expected, Right to Left.

However, When I copy and paste text, the first 10 or so characters are not visible.

When I delete the Arabic text upto the 1st character that appears on the edge of the screen, it then scrolls back to the missing characters.

[There are 4 letters before the first letter, which don't appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez12r.jpg)

This is only an issue on the Samsung Tablet (Android 4.1.2 (API 16))

XML for EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_arabic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="@drawable/border_gray"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Enter Arabic"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:shadowColor="@color/light_gray"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="2"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/zeb_blue_skype" />
```

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301248/6021469

Answer (score 0):

can you try this ? (it works in LinearLayout)

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Comment: what is your mobile language ? arabic  ?