# EditText, How to start typing from end to beginning?

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext

I have an EditText where the user can put in a desired amount of products.

Now what i wish to do is, that the EditText input starts from the end and fills up to the beginning.

Example:

Amount:  _ _ _ _ 4 5

and not

Amount:  4 5 _ _ _ _

The _ _ _ should demonstrate the EditText.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813310/how-do-i-position-the-cursor-on-the-right-in-edittext)

Comment: add android:gravity="end" to the `EditText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [**`android:gravity="end"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#END)

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="end"
     android:hint="type here" />
```

You can use

```
android:textDirection="rtl" // Works if you set MIN API level 17
```

Answer (score 0):

try use `android:gravity="end"` of `Edittext`:

like below code

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="end"
     android:hint="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `android:gravity="start"` to your `Editext`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work.

```
 <EditText
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="right"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add the below line in editText `android:textDirection="anyRtl"` or for more detail [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301191/how-to-make-my-edit-text-type-right-to-left)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill EditText from end try below code...

`android:gravity="end"`

Answer (score 0):

you may use multiple EditTexts with input type of numbers and control focus flow programatically.